# What does padma purana say about women?

Tags: puranas, women, padma-purana

I need to know how are women portrayed, treated and what does padma purana say about women?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: why specifically the padma purana?Why not other texts?What prompted u to ask this Qn?What did you research about it?What were you conclusions/inferences?What are your doubts now regarding the same?Have you searched the website for similar Qns?Have you even read the Padma Purana first yourself???

Comment: It would help in getting answers if you are a bit more specific about what you want to ask about women in Padma Purāṇa. Are you asking about the presence of misogynism in the text, by any chance or deification of women? Is there something you read in Padma Purāṇa or some other text, which you are indirectly referring to? There is nothing wrong with your question, it's just way too broad and lacks specificity. It seems more of a thesis topic rather than a specific question.
You are a new member, perhaps this would help https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask